# Grouping SQL results only for continuous time intervals (oracle sql)

Tags: sql, gaps-and-islands

I have issues with continuous time intervals. I have following data in table.

```
ID      startDate   endDate
------- ----------- ------------
5549    2008-05-01  4712-12-31
5567    2008-04-17  2008-04-30 1
5567    2008-05-01  2008-07-31 1
5567    2008-09-01  4712-12-31 2
5569    2008-01-01  2008-08-31
5569    2008-09-01  2008-09-20
5569    2008-11-01  4712-12-31  
5589    2008-04-18  2008-04-30
5589    2008-05-01  4712-12-31
5667    2008-05-01  2008-05-31
5667    2008-06-01  2008-07-31
5667    2008-08-01  2008-09-30
5667    2008-09-30  2008-12-31
5828    2008-06-03  4712-12-31
5867    2008-06-03  4712-12-31
6167    2008-11-01  4712-12-31
```

In a given time frame the below IDs don't have continuous time intervals, I want to exclude it. I want to exclude the ID (5567,5569) where there is no continuous time intervals. The results should be like below:

```
ID      START_DATE  END_DATE
------- ----------- -----------
5549    2008-05-01  4712-12-31
5589    2008-04-18  4712-12-31
5667    2008-05-01  2008-12-31
5828    2008-06-03  4712-12-31
5867    2008-06-03  4712-12-31
6167    2008-11-01  4712-12-31
```

Can anyone help this scenario?

#### Right now I'm using below SQL for continuous time interval results

```sql
  SELECT id, min (start_date) period_start, max (end_date) period_end
    FROM (SELECT id,
                 start_date,
                 end_date,
                 max (contig) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY end_date)
                     contiguous_group
            FROM (SELECT id,
                         start_date,
                         end_date,
                         CASE
                             WHEN    lag (end_date)
                                     OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY end_date) !=
                                         start_date - 1
                                  OR row_number ()
                                     OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY end_date) =
                                         1 THEN
                                 row_number ()
                                     OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY end_date)
                             ELSE
                                 NULL
                         END
                             contig
                    FROM t2))
GROUP BY id, contiguous_group
ORDER BY id, period_start
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following:

```
WITH mytbl AS (
SELECT 5549 as id, to_date('2008-05-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') start_date, to_date('4712-12-31', 'yyyy-mm-dd') end_date FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 5567, to_date('2008-04-17', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), to_date('2008-04-30', 'yyyy-mm-dd') FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 5567, to_date('2008-05-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), to_date('2008-07-31', 'yyyy-mm-dd') FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 5567, to_date('2008-09-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), to_date('4712-12-31', 'yyyy-mm-dd') FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 5569, to_date('2008-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), to_date('2008-08-31', 'yyyy-mm-dd') FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 5569, to_date('2008-09-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), to_date('2008-09-20', 'yyyy-mm-dd') FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 5569, to_date('2008-11-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), to_date('4712-12-31', 'yyyy-mm-dd') FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 5589, to_date('2008-04-18', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), to_date('2008-04-30', 'yyyy-mm-dd') FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 5589, to_date('2008-05-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), to_date('4712-12-31', 'yyyy-mm-dd') FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 5667, to_date('2008-05-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), to_date('2008-05-31', 'yyyy-mm-dd') FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 5667, to_date('2008-06-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), to_date('2008-07-31', 'yyyy-mm-dd') FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 5667, to_date('2008-08-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), to_date('2008-09-30', 'yyyy-mm-dd') FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 5667, to_date('2008-09-30', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), to_date('2008-12-31', 'yyyy-mm-dd') FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 5828, to_date('2008-06-03', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), to_date('4712-12-31', 'yyyy-mm-dd') FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 5867, to_date('2008-06-03', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), to_date('4712-12-31', 'yyyy-mm-dd') FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 6167, to_date('2008-11-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), to_date('4712-12-31', 'yyyy-mm-dd') FROM dual),
     derivedTbl AS
         (SELECT id, start_ end_date,
                 lead (start_date) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY start_date)
                     AS next_start_date
            FROM mytbl),
     t AS
         (SELECT id, start_date, end_date
            FROM derivedTbl t1
           WHERE NOT EXISTS
                         (SELECT 1
                            FROM derivedTbl t2
                           WHERE     t2.id = t1.id
                                 AND t2.next_start_date IS NOT NULL
                                 AND t2.next_start_date > t2.end_date + 1))
  SELECT id, min (start_date) period_start, max (end_date) period_end
    FROM t
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id;
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
ID      PERIOD_START  PERIOD_END
------- ------------- ----------
5549    2008-05-01    4712-12-31
5589    2008-04-18    4712-12-31
5667    2008-05-01    2008-12-31
5828    2008-06-03    4712-12-31
5867    2008-06-03    4712-12-31
6167    2008-11-01    4712-12-31
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach to solving this.  Find out which rows are starting a new date sequence, because they don't start on the day after the previous one.  Then take the cumulative sum.  This identifies the sequence.  Aggregating on the resulting value give you the results you want.

```
select id, min(start_date) as period_start, max(end_date) as period_end
from (select t.*, sum(seqflag) over (id order by start_date) as groupid
      from (select t2.*,
                   (case when end_date = lag(end_date) over (partition by id order by end_date) 
                         then 0 else 1
                    end) as seqflag
            from t2 t2
           ) t
     ) t
group by id, groupid;
```

The SQL Fiddle is [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/25082).

Comment: Hello Gordan & Rachacha, Thank you very much for your quick help, will check and let you know . I’m little poor in sql.... is there any way to get the generic sql?. Right now in db, we have millions of records, the sql has to check the continuous time intervals and has to eliminate the interval gap ID’s. Please give me some direction.
Thanks in advance